How to show marker again when user moves away from it flutter maps
I am displaying a map with flutter maps. Currently I have a marker plotted on a specific long and lat.
I am trying to implement a feature where users can press a button and then they will be back to the marker position even when they have moved far away
I implemented at button as below:
Align(
                alignment: Alignment(0.94, 0.95),
              
                child: Container(
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                       
                        
                       print('hello');

                    },

                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.near_me_sharp,
                      size: 30,
                    ),
                    
                    color: Colors.blue,

                    
                  ),

code where I display the map
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlutterMap(
        
        options: const MapOptions (
        initialCenter: LatLng(38.8977, -77.0365),
        initialZoom: 19,
        interactionOptions:
          InteractionOptions(flags: ~InteractiveFlag.doubleTapZoom)
      ), 
      children: [ 
              openStreetMapTileLayer
        CircleLayer(
            circles: [
              CircleMarker(
                point: const LatLng(38.8977, -77.0365),
                radius: 30,
                borderColor: Colors.blue,
                borderStrokeWidth: 5,
                useRadiusInMeter: true,
                color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 206, 192, 192).withOpacity(0.5))
            ]
            
        ),
      ],
    );


trying to make a feature similar to maps on iphone where when a button is clicked the screen re-orients itelf to its original view
